# Convert "6/14/2012:8:12 PM" to Milliseconds in Java script or DOJO

Tags: java, dojo, milliseconds

"6/14/2012:8:12 PM" want to convert it to Milliseconds (like 1338537600000) using Java Script or Dojo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:
1. Convert your string into a javascript date.
2. Call date.getTime().

Comment: Then multiply by 1,000 for milliseconds.

Comment: date.getTime() returns milliseconds.

Comment: Misunderstood something very basic, haven't I? Scratch that.

Comment: You will need to manually parse your date string. I'll post a jsfiddle for you shortly.

Comment: Thanks Josh that would be really helpful .

Comment: Your datetime format is odd, so its a little inelegant. It'll get you started though: http://jsfiddle.net/GUw8r/

Comment: Thanks Josh . But After I convert this millisecond to date I got a different date, 1,362,629,520,000 is Wed Mar 06 23:12:00 EST 2013

Comment: Oops. Forgot to subtract 1 from the year: http://jsfiddle.net/GUw8r/2/. Anyway, this should get you close enough to tweak to make sure it works right.